# What Bible passage does this $1,000,000 dollar bill reference?

Tags: reference-request

Got this neat dollar bill on a trip to D.C.. Turns out it was an advertisement for a church. The back of the bill is a story about Jesus and something about becoming a Christian. But I digress:

[image]
What I am curious about is the upper left. I am not Christian at all, but I love to read through the Bible because of the stories inside.  The code reads: `JN316 D0UB3L13V3`.

I know the first part translates to "Genesis", literally read "Jeneisix", but I'm curious about the last part, something I have no idea of.

Some guesses I had was that it was "Double Eve", but I don't get how that would make sense in the context of a passage from the book (Genesis Double:Eve?). Or I thought it was Double Leave, but still I have no idea what it means.

Could anyone help me out here? I can post the back if anyone would like, but I prefer not to give publicity to the organization in question.

Comment: It's actually "John 3:16 Do you believe". (Ah-ha! My |337-reading skills have paid off!)

Comment: Whoa, I thought the first word was Genesis, J (GE) - N3 (NE) - 16 (ISIS)

Comment: Why Abe Lincoln?  He was a great guy and all, but shouldn't that be a picture of Jesus?

Comment: @thinlyveiledquestionmark I have found ones like these folded and crumpled up on grocery store shelves. I was upset that it wasn't real money. They were actually modeled after the five dollar bill, so it was quickly recognized as legitimate money, but then upon inspection you see you've been hoodwinked.

Comment: @thinlyveiledquestionmark: Just don't try to [spend the money](http://www.cnet.com/news/man-accused-of-trying-to-buy-microwave-with-1-million-bill/).

Comment: I have removed the reference to "astroturfing" while retaining the intent of the post. So can we please stop arguing about this *very minor point*?

Comment: @Flimzy thanks - I considered doing that, but thought it might be rude without seeing where the OP ws coming from. The point might have been minor in terms of the meaining of the post, but given the meaning of the word, it was effectively a slander against the church who produced the item. Deleting my previous comments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first part is short for [John 3:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+3%3A16&version=KJV) which reads (KJV):

> For God so loved the world, that he gave his only begotten Son, that whosoever believeth in him should not perish, but have everlasting life.

The second part is short for Do You Believe, with 3 in the place of E, and is asked in reference to the aforementioned verse.

The second part is referring to the invitation to believe on Jesus for eternal life, asking, "Do you believe?"

Comment: What does "D4" mean, though?

Comment: @Zoe- Is there another Mighty Ducks sequel in the works?

Comment: @TenthJustice I am definitely gonna ask my mentor about this tmr and come back with the news :)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct about JN316 probably being a reference to John 3:16, and D0UB3L13V3 asking the question "Do you believe".

Just wanted to add about the "D4" that this may mean "Died for", i.e. it is a reference to that Jesus gave his life in behalf of humankind.

Comment: I never noticed that, nice find

Comment: @thinlyveiledquestionmark I'm skeptical about the meaning of  D4. If you can find evidence that the designers of the bill chose it in hopes it would be interpreted as "died for", I will upvote this. On real bills I found "A1", "B2", and "L12". They don't have a lot to work with. "Died for" seems plausible, but maybe they just put something there that matched the usual pattern.

Comment: @disciple This is not my answer.

Comment: My mistake. My prior comment should have been directed to @eravn.